# How to Get Id of Selected DropDownList vale after Submit in MVC4 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
    'public string Country;
    public List<SelectListItem> DdlCountryList { get; set; }
    public string State;
    public List<SelectListItem> DdlStateList { get; set; }
    private List<SelectListItem> _listItems;
    public string District = "District";
    public List<SelectListItem> DdlDistrictList { get; set; }
    public string Village = "Village";
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DdlVillageList { get; set; }
    public string Crop = "Crop";
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DdlCropList { get; set; }
    public string Year = "Year";
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DdlYearList { get; set; }
    public string ProductionCode = "ProductionCode";
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DdlProductionList { get; set; }
    public string Season = "Season";
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DdlSeasonList { get; set; }'

> Tha Above is My Model GlobalSearchModel
> on load Iam filling Values,.. and By using Jquery change function i am calling Values how    to get the Id's of Selected DropDownValues

public ActionResult Index()
    {

        GlobalSearchModel objGlobalSearchModel = new GlobalSearchModel();
        return View(objGlobalSearchModel);
    }
```

> This is My Controller's Action method, i am filling Default Values for DropDownList on Constructor of GlobalSearchModel(); like 'Select'

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FilterMapDetails(GlobalSearchModel objGlobalSearchModel)
    {
        //Logic GoesHere then i will return values

        return View("Index", objGlobalSearchModel);

    }
```

> The above is my PostMethod called when submitted, Thanks in Advance

Comment: please post view code as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view model you should have corresponding properties for each drop down that will be bound to the DropDownList and will hold the selected values.

For example:

```
public string SelectedCountry { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> DdlCountryList { get; set; }
```

and then inside your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCountry, Model.DdlCountryList)
```

and finally in your post action simply use the `SelectedCountry` property from your model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FilterMapDetails(GlobalSearchModel objGlobalSearchModel)
{
    // objGlobalSearchModel.SelectedCountry will contain the selected value

    return View("Index", objGlobalSearchModel);
}
```

Comment: @darin : if the `DropDownList` is not bound to any model how can the id be accessed.